# The diophantine equation $z^2=a^2+bx^2+cy^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Is there a way to obtain (enumerate) the integer solutions $(x,y,z)$ of the following quadratic Diophantine equation

$z^2=a^2+bx^2+cy^2$

where $a$ is an integer and $b, c$ are positive integers?
I have checked the literature on Diophantine equations but could not find anything useful. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see [Legendre's theorem](https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=legendre%27s%20theorem%20about%20diophantine%20equations)

Comment: Of course you can solve it.  The only cumbersome formula. And decisions are determined by Pell equations.  For example for some simple cases, you can write.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351491/integral-solutions-of-hyperboloid-x2y2-z2-1/709219#709219  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298053/quadratic-diophantine-equations/710766#710766   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74931/integral-solutions-of-x2y21-z2/789972#789972

Answer (score 0):

I think you can at first solve the well known equation $w^{2} + a^{2} = z^{2}$  for convenient values of a and go after to the equation $w^2 = bx^2 + cy^2$ which is solved in the book of L. J. Mordell “Diophantine Equations” (Academic Press. London and New York, 1969 page 44).

Answer (score 0):

We have at least two, $(0,0,a)$ and $(0,0,-a).$

We have infinitely many solutions to
$$ b x^2 + c y^2 - z^2 = -a^2.  $$

It is possible, however, that no solutions need be primitive: under some choices of $a$ it may be that all solutions have $x,y,z$ all divisible by $a.$ An early example of this (not quite the pattern your form takes) is due to C. L. Siegel, see pages 168 and 253 in [CASSELS](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html).

Actually, an easy example is given by
$$ 3 x^2 + 3 y^2 - z^2 = -9.  $$
We see immediately that $z^2$ is divisible by $3,$ therefore $z$ is divisible by $3.$ As a result, $3x^2 + 3 y^2$ is divisible by $9,$ so that $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by $3.$ Since Legendre symbol $(-1|3) = -1,$ we see that $x,y$ are also both divisible by $3.$

Find a solution ( the smallest one with $u,v > 0$ is best) to $u^2 - b v^2 = 1.$
We can now replace any of the  solutions we have found so far with 
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto   (ux+vz,y, bvx+uz). $$

Find a solution ( the smallest one with $p,q > 0$ is best) to $p^2 - c q^2 = 1.$
We can  replace any of the  solutions we have found so far with 
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto   (x,py+qz, cqy+pz). $$