# What's special about the Mordell curve $y^2 = x^3+7823$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In this [MO comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42016/algorithms-for-finding-rational-points-on-an-elliptic-curve/42031#comment719447_42031), William Stein remarked that a "...spectacular example in which *Heegner* points fail in practice" is the Mordell curve,
$$y^2 = x^3+N,\quad N = 7823$$

but doing a $4$-descent succeeds.

The article [*$4$-descent on the Elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3+7823$*](https://www.wstein.org/edu/Spring2003/21n/projects/jennifer/jennifer.ps) pointed out that until 2002, the Mordell-Weil generators of all Mordell curves have been found for all $N<10000$ except that one. It would turn out to be the large,

$$x=\frac{2263582143321421502100209233517777}{143560497706190989485475151904721}$$

However, I had asked about the [number $7824$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806669/the-boolean-pythagorean-triples-problem-a-200-terabyte-proof-and-d-163) before so I knew that curve was in fact,

$$y^2=x^3+(48\times\color{blue}{163})-1$$

> **Q:** Is it coincidence that the largest *Heegner* number $d=163$ appears here, and that it needs a $4$-descent, unlike smaller numbers?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ssnw2GA657s